# How to align a text relating to another entity

Tags: graphics, animation

I am creating an animation that shows the fall of a circle.

But the text of my animation is not falling in order uniform.

I need to enter the information that the text should remain aligned the `LEFT`, but I don´t know where to place this information.

```
y[t_] = y[t] /. 
  First@NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0}, 
    y[t], {t, 0, 2}];
tb = Table[Graphics[
    {
     EdgeForm[Black],
     LightGray,
     Rectangle[{-.5, -15}, {xR = .5, yR = y[0]}],
     Red,
     PointSize[0.1],
     Point[{px = xR + 1, py = y[time]}],
     Text[
      Style["Time = " <> ToString[time], FontSize -> 15, Bold, 
       Blue], {0, yR + 1}],
     Text[
      Style["Position = " <> ToString[y[time]], FontSize -> 12, Bold, 
       Green], {Left, px + 3.5, py}],
     Green,
     Thickness[0.03],
     Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]
     },
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 7}, {-16, 7}}
    ], {time, 0, 2, .01}];
Export["Queda.gif", tb]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align text it is best to use the 3rd argument of `Text`. In your case,

```
With[{grn = Darker[Green, .4], xR = .5, yR = 5.},
   yF = NDSolveValue[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == yR, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 2}];
   images =
      Module[{px = xR + 1, py},
        Table[
          py = yF[time];
          Graphics[
            {EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, Rectangle[{-xR, -15}, {xR, yR}],
             Red, PointSize[0.1], Point[{px, py}],
             Text[
               Style[Row[{"Time = ", time}], 15, Bold, Blue],
               {0, yR + 1}],
             Text[
               Style[Row[{"Position = \n", py}], 12, Bold, grn],
               {px, py},
               {1.8, 0}], (* push text to left *)
             grn, Thickness[0.03], Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
             PlotRange -> {{-10, 7}, {-16, 7}}],
          {time, Subdivide[0., 2., 4]}]]];

GraphicsRow @ images
```

[image: images]

The 3rd argument of `Text` nudges text in the *local* coordinate system of the text box. In that system, the text box ranges from -1 to +1 from left to right. The 2nd coordinate of `Text` is nominally at `{0, 0}` in text box coordinates, but the 3rd argument allows you to specify a new position for the 2nd coordinate in *text box coordinates*. Thus, the 1.8 in `{1.8, 0}` says that `{px, py}` should be 1.8 half-widths of the box to the *right* of the center of the box, which means the center of the text ends up being placed .9 text box widths to the *left* of `{px, py}`. Takes some getting used to, but that's the way it works.